# Chain Lightning and Expansive Spellstrike

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, targeting, magus

[Expansive Spellstrike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2849) allows for using spells that can "target a creature or that [have] an area of a burst, cone, or line (abiding by any other restrictions of Spellstrike)" with Spellstrike. It has this caveat on spells with multiple targets: "If the spell lets you select a number of targets, it instead targets only the creature you attacked with your Strike."

[Chain Lightning](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=33) targets "1 creature, plus any number of additional creatures". Clearly it can be used with Expansive Spellstrike, but **do I get to actually hit multiple creatures with Chain Lightning**? On one hand, it seems like I should be able to chain the lightning, so long as I start with the first creature I Spellstrike, since the spell functionally seems to target one creature and then have additional possible targets (dependent on the creature's save). But on the other hand, it is a spell that targets multiple creatures, so maybe I'm limited to just hitting the first?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No.

From my read of Expansive Spellstrike, and the prerequisite Spellstrike, you cannot target multiple creatures while using Chain Lightning alone.

> One Target: The spell targets only the target of your Strike, even if it normally allows more targets. Some feats let you affect more creatures.

> If the spell lets you select a number of targets, it instead targets only the creature you attacked with your Strike.